# Underscores in Company Name when using C# Settings & LocalFileSettingsProvider

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I've noticed that when using the Settings object that's created by a Windows Forms application, any spaces in the "Company Name" field of the assembly info are replaced by underscores in the path of the user.config file.  For example, in XP the path to the user.config file will be something like:

```
\Documents and Settings\user\Local Settings\Application Data\Company_Name_Here\App\Version\user.config
```

But this only seems to be happening to my own applications.  I've got lots of .NET applications installed on my machine, but none of the other directory names under Application Data contain underscores (the spaces are preserved).

What gives?  It's not a big deal, but I'm just wondering why this only seems to be happening to my applications, and if there's a way to change this behavior that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Quoting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rprabhu/archive/2005/06/29/433979.aspx) someone who worked at Microsoft

> <Company Name> - is typically the string specified by the AssemblyCompanyAttribute (with the caveat that the string is escaped and truncated as necessary, and if not specified on the assembly, we have a fallback procedure).

and

> Q: Why is the path so obscure? Is there any way to change/customize it?
>
> A: The path construction algorithm has to meet certain rigorous requirements in terms of security, isolation and robustness. While we tried to make the path as easily discoverable as possible by making use of friendly, application supplied strings, it is not possible to keep the path totally simple without running into issues like collisions with other apps, spoofing etc.
>
> The LocalFileSettingsProvider does not provide a way to change the files in which settings are stored. Note that the provider itself doesn't determine the config file locations in the first place - it is the configuration system. If you need to store the settings in a different location for some reason, the recommended way is to write your own SettingsProvider. This is fairly simple to implement and you can find samples in the .NET 2.0 SDK that show how to do this. Keep in mind however that you may run into the same isolation issues mentioned above .

might give some hint of explanation.

So other applications might have used an individual settings provider that supports whitespaces.

The restrictions of the default .NET settings provider are also mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> Each application setting must have a unique name; the name can be any combination of letters, numbers, or an underscore that does not start with a number, and cannot contain spaces. The name can be changed through the Name property.