# CompanyName spaces replaced with underscore in AppData Folder

Tags: c#, configuration-files, special-folders

all.

I'm getting a weird issue with AppData folder.
I'm trying to access the **user.config** in AppData\Local\[Company Name]\... folder.
[Company Name] is set in **AssemblyInfo.cs** by **AssemblyCompany** attribute and it **contains spaces**.
Lets say its "My Company Name".
I would would expect that the path to user config would contain
AppData\Local[**My Company Name**]... folder, but instead its 
AppData\Local[**My_Company_Name**]... (spaces replaced by underscore).

Why is this happening? How can I get the correct location of user settings?

I cannot use Application.UserAppDataPath property because I'm on Console application,
so I need to build the path manually.

Any help would be appreciated.
P.S.
OS is Win 7 x64

Comment: Do you need something more complicated than `"My Company Name".Replace(" ","_")`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I build Application.UserAppDataPath inside class libraries (that don't have an Application object)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736882/how-can-i-build-application-userappdatapath-inside-class-libraries-that-dont-h)

Comment: Firstly, I'm just curios, why this is happening.<br/>
Secondly, the behavior is inconsistent. Same Company name in Roaming folder is created as expected with whitespaces.<br/>
Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData for local folder,
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData for roaming folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Underscores in Company Name when using C# Settings & LocalFileSettingsProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717077/underscores-in-company-name-when-using-c-sharp-settings-localfilesettingsprovi)